# Decimate f-curves using python

Tags: python, animation, animation-nodes, fcurves

In blender 2.82 I want to decimate all the f-curves in active action, how can I override the context to make the script work with Animation Nodes Script Node?

```
import bpy
if decimate:
    bpy.context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
    bpy.ops.graph.decimate(mode='RATIO', remove_ratio=0.92)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import bpy  
def simplify_fcurves():
    C=bpy.context
    old_area_type = C.area.type
    C.area.type='GRAPH_EDITOR'
    bpy.ops.graph.decimate(mode='ERROR', remove_ratio=0.698113, remove_error_margin=0.5)
    C.area.type=old_area_type    
simplify_fcurves()
```